# How to read electricity meter using Computer Vision + Tesseract?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, tesseract

I have to write an app for reading an electricity meter (analog and digital).

I'm starting with the analog. I read that I can use computer vision for preprocessing (threshold, find contours, etc), and then pass the detected characters to an OCR program like Tesseract. But I couldn't find the perfect detection methods. Sometimes it works for some images but I have to tune the parameters for the others.

I checked out other apps like [Anyline.com](https://anyline.com/products/ocr-meter-reading/) which has great accuracy. How do I achieve such accuracy with traditional computer vision? Or should I go with machine/deep learning? Actually I'm no expert on this field. Have been exploring about a year. My background is regular apps (web, mobile) programming. So, any advice is highly appreciated.

Here are some examples of my current effort:

[image: Meter 1] 
[image: Result 1]

[image: Meter 2] 
[image: Result 2]

[image: Image 3]
[image: Result 3]

Comment: were you able to achieve this using android?

Answer (score 0):

If you do consider deep learning, I highly suggest you check out the MNIST handwritten digits challenge [link] http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

This should set you up to solve that problem, there are plenty of pretrained models and a variety of information on how to approach this.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried some basics of deep learning, like mnist handwritten and mnist fashion. tried own data also. and  I'm on my way to explore more. But it's a long way to master. I'm still having trouble with overfitting or something. and all those confusing terms. tbc..

Comment: What I'm curious now is about traditional computer vision techniques and Tesseract can also give highly acceptable results such as Anyline and Openalpr for example. I read that they use Tesseract as the OCR. I've tried training custom fonts for Tesseract. It works for the other project. But for this particular case, I'm having trouble in detecting and segmenting characters accurately and how to pass to Tesseract for accurate OCR.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS 13 or higher, you don't need *any* 3rd party solutions for that. In fact, Apple provides sample code for scanning phone numbers with phone camera, along with a dedicated video in WWDC 2019. Not sure about Android.

Comment: I'm targeting Raspberry Pi and Android.. I.'m using OpenCV for the library